# Alias name for a method in Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ip'm trying to refactor my gallery model and I have an issue.

I'm using an rss generator that call on my content the methods "summary" and "permalink"

In my gallery.rb the equivalent column of the db are "body" and "slug".

Now I have these two methods:

```
  def summary
    body
  end

  def permalink
    slug
  end
```

I'm trying to create an alias in this way:

```
  alias :summary :body
  alias :permalink :slug
```

but it doesn't work.

What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to use [`alias_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods/alias_attribute), like this:

```
alias_attribute :summary, :body
alias_attribute :permalink, :slug
```

Comment: @RobertoPezzali did you try my answer? Did it help?